# Finding duplicates based on first n characters of a string in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, duplicates

I'm new to the forum and SQL, and I'm hoping this will be an easy question to answer. I am working with an Oracle db, and I am wanting to search for duplicate companies in a table by only searching on the first 10 or so characters in the company name string.

For example: if I have `'ABC Corp'`, `'ABC Co'` and `'ABC Corporation'` listed separately in my table, I want to be able to search for `'ABC C'` and have all companies returned. Since I am looking for duplicates, I only want to return results where the sub-string occurs more than once. It seems like it should be pretty easy, but I cannot get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: you wrote "I cannot get it to work". StackOverflow is about helping people solve their code problems, not giving them the finished product. You should update your question with you best attempt to solve the problem and some description of what output you're currently getting. Use 4 spaces at the front of each line to have it format correctly as code/data. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you a list of all substrings that appear multiple times in the table:

```
select 
  substr(name, 0, 6), 
  count(substr(name, 0, 6)) 
from test
group by substr(name, 0, 6)
having count(substr(name, 0, 6)) > 1
```

and this returns a list of companies whose substring appears more than once:

```
select 
  name
from test test1
where (
  select count(*) 
  from test 
  where substr(test.name, 0, 6) = substr(test1.name, 0, 6)) > 1
```